# Compare datetetimes in tables not working because of daylight saving time (ORA-01850)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

So I have a two tables, and I want to filter by comparing the datetime:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    data,
    foo
WHERE
    data."DATE" > foo."DATE"
```

Since `data."DATE"` contains datetimes that include the daylight saving time (e.g., 2021-10-31 24:34) I get the Oracle error `ORA-01850: hour must be between 0 and 23`.
But the datetime is correct! Because this belongs to the moment when the timezone is shifted and thus they add 1 hour to the day.

Can't Oracle tell this?

Comment: Also in DST is no hour 24. It is 0:34

Comment: You mean you're storing dates in character format? Unless you really screwed things, a date column in Oracle will not allow you to enter data with 24:34. And it is a bad idea to have a column called DATE, which is a reserved word.

Comment: If you want to work with DST data, then have a look at the data type "TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE" - it takes all the complexity of DST and timezone away from the client side

Comment: This is nothing to do with DST really. Oracle's DATE data type does not have time zone information and so isn't DST-aware. The error means one of your columns is a date and the other is a string; the comparison is forcing implicit conversion of the string to a date, and - as Jens said - your example with '24:34' cannot be converted, hence the error. This is why you shouldn't stores dates as strings, as they can contain any old rubbish. If you have used some bespoke logic to store datetimes as strings then you will need bespoke logic to untangle that - if it's possible at all.

Comment: In most countries that have DST, the time change occurs at either 01:00-02:00 or 02:00-03:00 and you will either have that hour twice (in Autumn) or skip that hour (in Spring). You **NEVER** have an hour 24:00-24:59.

Comment: Never - ever - use strings to store dates.  Either use unix epochs (which have no ambiguity regarding daylight savings, etc), `DATE` to represent the date&time in `UTC`, or timezone aware datatypes such as `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`  For example, having used a string, when the clocks 'fall back' from 1:59am to 1:00am, you have ***no*** way to distinguish whether the 1am string represents a time Before the clocks changed or After the clocks changed.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data that replicates the problem; an explanation of the logic you are using (including why you think 24:34 is a valid time of day - yes due to DST some days might have 25 hours but they repeat an hour early in the morning rather than adding an extra hour at the end); and the expected output for your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a table `data_tbl` with the column of type `DATE` (includes time always in Oracle) and the second table with date and time written as a string (VarChar2) then you could have something like '24:34' inside that string and consider it as time.

There are a few questions here like, time after 24 hours should belong to next day (!?), someone could enter the time like 33:34 too (!?), or even worse - mess up the date part (!?).

If your data have just the mistaken hours (24) and all of the rest is OK then you should convert that string to a date correcting the wrong (24) hour to '00' and then compare two dates.

Here is the sample data with two dates in second (foo) table one of type `DATE` and the other of type `VARCHAR2` so we could see the difference in code:

```sql
WITH
    data_tbl AS
        (
            Select 1 "EVENT_ID", To_Date('2022-08-12 21:20:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "EVENT_DATE_DATE", 'some other data' "SOME_COLUMN" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "EVENT_ID", To_Date('2022-08-20 19:12:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "EVENT_DATE_DATE", 'some other data' "SOME_COLUMN" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "EVENT_ID", To_Date('2022-09-01 00:34:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "EVENT_DATE_DATE", 'some other data' "SOME_COLUMN" From Dual 
        ),
    foo_tbl AS
        (   
            Select 101 "FOO_ID", 1 "EVENT_ID", To_Date('2022-08-12 19:20:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "FOO_DATE_DATE", '2022-08-12 19:20:00' "FOO_CHAR_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 102 "FOO_ID", 1 "EVENT_ID", To_Date('2022-08-12 22:40:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "FOO_DATE_DATE", '2022-08-12 22:40:00' "FOO_CHAR_DATE" From Dual Union All
            
            Select 103 "FOO_ID", 2 "EVENT_ID", To_Date('2022-08-20 19:10:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "FOO_DATE_DATE", '2022-08-20 19:10:00' "FOO_CHAR_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 104 "FOO_ID", 2 "EVENT_ID", To_Date('2022-08-20 19:20:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "FOO_DATE_DATE", '2022-08-20 19:20:00' "FOO_CHAR_DATE" From Dual Union All
            
            Select 105 "FOO_ID", 3 "EVENT_ID", To_Date('2022-09-01 00:30:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "FOO_DATE_DATE", '2022-09-01 24:30:00' "FOO_CHAR_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 106 "FOO_ID", 3 "EVENT_ID", To_Date('2022-09-01 00:34:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "FOO_DATE_DATE", '2022-09-01 24:34:00' "FOO_CHAR_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 107 "FOO_ID", 3 "EVENT_ID", To_Date('2022-09-01 02:20:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "FOO_DATE_DATE", '2022-09-01 02:20:00' "FOO_CHAR_DATE" From Dual 
        )
```

FOO_IDs 105 and 106 have '24' for hour in the column FOO_CHAR_DATE
First the query and the result for the case that there is just FOO_DATE_DATE here (without VARCHAR2 date) - this is pretty straight forward:

```sql
SELECT
    d.*,
    f.FOO_ID, f.FOO_DATE_DATE
FROM
    data_tbl d
INNER JOIN
    foo_tbl f ON (f.EVENT_ID = d.EVENT_ID)
WHERE
    d.EVENT_DATE_DATE > f.FOO_DATE_DATE
/*
  EVENT_ID EVENT_DATE_DATE SOME_COLUMN         FOO_ID FOO_DATE_DATE
---------- --------------- --------------- ---------- -------------
         1 12-AUG-22       some other data        101 12-AUG-22     
         2 20-AUG-22       some other data        103 20-AUG-22     
         3 01-SEP-22       some other data        105 01-SEP-22    
*/
```

To get the same result with VARCHAR2 data your where condition should look something like here:

```sql
...  ...  ...
WHERE
    d.EVENT_DATE_DATE > To_Date(SubStr(f.FOO_CHAR_DATE, 1, 11) ||  
    REPLACE(SubStr(f.FOO_CHAR_DATE, 12, 2), '24', '00') ||
    SubStr(f.FOO_CHAR_DATE, 14), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

... much more complicated with endless opportunities to have something wrong.
Finally here are full paralel data with converted values to and from date and varchar (both ways)

```sql
SELECT
    d.*,
    f.FOO_ID, f.FOO_DATE_DATE, f.FOO_CHAR_DATE,
  To_Char(d.EVENT_DATE_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "EVENT_DATE_STR",
  To_Char(
  To_Date(SubStr(f.FOO_CHAR_DATE, 1, 11) ||  
    REPLACE(SubStr(f.FOO_CHAR_DATE, 12, 2), '24', '00') ||
    SubStr(f.FOO_CHAR_DATE, 14), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "FOO_DATE_STR_FROM_CHAR"
FROM
    data_tbl d
INNER JOIN
    foo_tbl f ON (f.EVENT_ID = d.EVENT_ID)
WHERE
    d.EVENT_DATE_DATE > To_Date(SubStr(f.FOO_CHAR_DATE, 1, 11) ||  
    REPLACE(SubStr(f.FOO_CHAR_DATE, 12, 2), '24', '00') ||
    SubStr(f.FOO_CHAR_DATE, 14), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
/*
  EVENT_ID EVENT_DATE_DATE SOME_COLUMN         FOO_ID FOO_DATE_DATE FOO_CHAR_DATE       EVENT_DATE_STR      FOO_DATE_STR_FROM_CHAR
---------- --------------- --------------- ---------- ------------- ------------------- ------------------- ----------------------
         1 12-AUG-22       some other data        101 12-AUG-22     2022-08-12 19:20:00 2022-08-12 21:20:00 2022-08-12 19:20:00    
         2 20-AUG-22       some other data        103 20-AUG-22     2022-08-20 19:10:00 2022-08-20 19:12:00 2022-08-20 19:10:00    
         3 01-SEP-22       some other data        105 01-SEP-22     2022-09-01 24:30:00 2022-09-01 00:34:00 2022-09-01 00:30:00  
*/
```

Comment: Thanks. I discovered the error. In my data, I don't have a string. Instead I have a column of date, and then another column called period, which goes from 1-25 in case of DST. when I concatenate those columns I do it as strings and then convert back as date.